# Value of custom field in JIRA webhook JSON is null

Tags: jira

I have created a webhook that fires when a workflow transition occurs. The screen that appears before transitioning has a couple of custom fields. 
I fill in those custom fields and then the webhook fires, but then the JSON that is sent by the webhook has all those custom fields with null values, like this:

```
"customfield_10801": null,
"customfield_10802": null,
"customfield_10803": null,
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I need to get the value of those fields in the JSON.

Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that them custom fields are the correct ones that you want.  If you create a RequestBin and have the webhook fire to that, then search for the values that you have inputted it should work.  For example I have a customfield with when I enter a number like this:  "customfield_12650":214.0.  But other custom fields have null values that I do not enter information about.  For example:  "customfield_10110":null

Comment: yes, I am sure. I found the cause of the problem, but thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the order in which the webhook was triggered. I don't know why in this case the webhook was triggered BEFORE storing the issue in the database. In the transition post functions I changed the order so that the webhook as triggered AFTER storing the issue in the database.